# Align two images in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, alignment

I have two images (see below). These images represent the contours of a pair of cables and were captured using laser based 3D triangulation. The first image is captured with the left camera, while the second one with the right camera. As can be seen, these images are partially overlapping. The left part on the first image partly corresponds to the left part on the second image. The same holds for the right part. I want to merge these two images into one image so that the corresponding parts overlap.

Next to these images, I also have the following information at my disposal:

- A 3x3 homography matrix `H` of left and right camera
- Intrinsic camera parameters `K` of left and right camera
- Distortion coefficients `D` (9 of them) of left and right camera
- Offset `O` of left and right camera

This data is specified below.

In Halcon, I have tried to do this using mosaicking:

- Extract characteristic points in both images using Harris
- Compute a projective transformation matrix from one image to the other using Ransac.
- Apply the found projective transformation matrix.

This approach was however not successful. I am looking for a similar approach in OpenCV or Halcon **or** an approach (also in OpenCV or Halcon) that makes use of the calibration data I have at my disposal, such as the homography matrix and camera matrix.

Please provide ample explanations, if possible, since I am only starting out with Machine Vision.

[image]
[image]

```
Hl := [0.00175186,   4.73083e-05, -0.00108921,
       0.000780817, -0.00145615,   0.00118631,
       0.0534139,   -0.030823,     1.0        ]
Kl := [4578.21,   -5.05144, 759.766,
       0.0,     4576.87,    568.223,
       0.0,        0.0,       1.0   ]
Dl := [-0.12573, 0.0533453, -0.575361, -0.0130272, 0.00348033, 0.00852617, -0.0271142, 0.0176706, -0.00575124]
Ol := [0.0, 150.0]

Hr := [0.00173883, -2.94597e-05, 0.00109873,
      -0.00077676, -0.0014687,   0.00121393,
      -0.0653829,  -0.0443924,   1.0        ]
Kr := [4591.96,  -4.55317, 1284.74,
       0.0,    4591.19,     534.317,
       0.0,       0.0,        1.0   ]
Dr := [-0.110751, -0.349716, 3.86535, 0.017393, -0.00364957, -0.00633656, 0.0338833, -0.0212222, 0.00543694]
Or := [0.0, 100.0]
```

Comment: do you have access to the 3d point positions of the pixels, relative to the laser scanner.? ("were captured using laser based 3D triangulation")

Comment: No, I don't think so. Can I compute this using the data I have available, such as homography or camera matrix?

Comment: so the images arent captured with a 3d triangulating device like a laser scanner? those devices typically capture a 3d point cloud grid

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the way the images are captured or the direct output of that device. The only input I have available is the images and the calibration data, both specified in the question.

Comment: H is the 3d rigid transformation between zhe cameras, or the homography between the images? or the extrinsic parameters of the cameras?

Comment: @Micka I'm not entirely sure, but could it be that the matrix `Hl` together with `Ol` form the extrinsic parameters of the left camera (where `Hl` is the 3x3 rotation matrix and `Ol` is the translation)?

Comment: doesnt look like... can you try cv::warpPerspective with those homographies?

Comment: @Micka When I do `cv.warpPerspective`, I get a completely black image.

Comment: @JNevens, I was wondering whether you cropped or resized the images since the Xp and Yp values in the calibration matrices do not make sense to me (They are too big for an image of height 350px).

Answer (score 1):

Template matching would do the trick here. I played with it  a little, hope you find it usuful (Code below):

[image]

```
MAX_DISPARITY = 100;
imgL=double(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5tOJ.png'));
imgR=double(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1EQy.png'));
imgRfused = imgR;
minmax = @(v) [min(v) max(v)];
[imgLbw,n]=bwlabel(imgL);
nBlobs=2;
a=arrayfun(@(i) sum(imgLbw(:)==i),1:n);
[~,indx]=sort(a,'descend');
imgLbwC=bsxfun(@eq,imgLbw,permute(indx(1:nBlobs),[3 1 2]));
imgLbwC =bsxfun(@times,imgLbwC,2.^permute(0:nBlobs-1,[3 1 2]));
imgLbwC  = sum(imgLbwC ,3);

src = zeros(nBlobs,4);
dst = zeros(nBlobs,4);

for i=1:nBlobs
    [y,x]=find(imgLbwC==i);
    mmx = minmax(x);
    mmy = minmax(y);
    ker = imgL(mmy(1):mmy(2),mmx(1):mmx(2));

    [yg,xg]=ndgrid(mmy(1):mmy(2),mmx(1):mmx(2));
    src(i,:)=[mmx(1) mmy(1) fliplr(size(ker))];


    imgR_ = imgR(:,mmx(1)-MAX_DISPARITY:mmx(2)+MAX_DISPARITY);
    c=conv2(imgR_ ,rot90(double(ker),2),'valid')./sqrt(conv2(imgR_.^2,ones(size(ker)),'valid'));
    [yy,xx]=find(c==max(c(:)),1);
    dst(i,:)=[src(i,1:2)+[xx yy-mmy(1)]+[-MAX_DISPARITY,0] fliplr(size(ker))];

    imgRfused(dst(i,2):dst(i,2)+dst(i,4),dst(i,1):dst(i,1)+dst(i,3)) = max(imgRfused(dst(i,2):dst(i,2)+dst(i,4),dst(i,1):dst(i,1)+dst(i,3)),imgL(src(i,2):src(i,2)+src(i,4),src(i,1):src(i,1)+src(i,3)));
end
imagesc(imgRfused);
axis image
colormap gray
```