# Align two images from two different cameras with the help of the intrinsic and extrinsic matrixes

Tags: python, image-processing, image-scaling, infrared, color-depth

I have two images : a picture, and a depth map image computed using a set of two IR sensors distinct from the first camera. But the two are not aligned:

[The image and its corresponding depth map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWY3V.png)

I also have the intrisic and extrinsic matrices of the cameras :

[instrinsic and extrinsic matrices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyvkK.png)

Is there a proper way to use those matrices and the depth in order to align the two images by considering them undistorted? I have not managed to find a helpfull python library. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

A somewhat similar  question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38791748/align-two-images-in-opencv), but it seems to me that it does not contain the desired answer.

Comment: Hi there! Any chance you could share what you've tried so far or what libraries you've looked at? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes. I have thought of placing 4 points on remarquable areas on the two images and then aligning the points with some affine transformation. There is also the open cv library and this [page](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html#calibration) of the documentation. That's a close topic but not really corresponding to my problem.

Comment: @Charbel-RaphaëlSegerie Hey, I have a similar problem. Did you find a resolution to yours?